# Trouble with an homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to prove that an injective map $f$ from the circle to a disk with a point removed, $Y$, is homotopic to a map that sends the circle to a point, $g$.
In order to do that, I have defined an homotopy from $f$ to the constant map $f(1)$ in this way:
\begin{align*}
H\colon \mathit{S}^{1} \times I \mapsto Y\\
(e^{2\pi si},t) \mapsto f(e^{2\pi (1-t)si})
\end{align*}
$H$ is an homotopy. After that, since $Y$ is path-connected, the constant map $f(1)$ and any constant map are going to be homotopic.
Therefore, because of the transitivity, I obtain that $f$ ang $g$ are homotopic. I haven't use the fact that $f$ is injective. Can someone tell me please where is my argument wrong?

Comment: Your homotopy does not seem to be a continuous map.

Comment: @Karen: When you write "circle", do you mean "closed interval $[0, 1]$"? (That interpretation would fix three issues: the one noted by fixedpt, the fact that a map from a circle to a punctured disk is generally _not_ homotopic to a constant map, and the fact that your proposed homotopy does in fact implicitly assume injectivity.)

Comment: I mean the circle of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I have assumed that the points of the circle are of the form $e^{2 \pi si}$ for $s\in [0,1]$. I don't understand why it is not continuous, if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Essentially you are contracting the circle into a point with your homotopy, then applying $f$. It's not $f$ that is the problem, but what you wrote within its brackets.

Comment: And in this case, since $f$ is an injective map I would obtain an open path in the punctured disk, so it would be possible to contract the path to a point of the disk, no?

Comment: My point is that it is impossible to contract a circle to a point continuously.

Comment: @Karen: The map $[0, 1] \times [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ defined by $(s, t) \mapsto (1-t)s$ is continuous, but the map $S^{1} \times [0, 1] \to S^{1}$ defined by $(\exp(2\pi si), t) \mapsto (\exp(2\pi s(1 - t)i)$ is discontinuous at $(1, 0)$, where the circle "breaks".

Comment: Why are you trying to prove that map is nullhomotopic?